# Getting the zero byte in the PutFile method in request body

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ms-wopi

We are getting the zero byte in the PutFile method in request body, but we can do the online editing of document and it is reflecting in other browsers as well (if we are editing the file in two browsers at same time ).

We are using ASP.Net Core and we are reading the request body like -

```
var bytes = new byte[context.Request.Body.Length];
context.Request.Body.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Can anyone please help us on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using following code -

```
byte[] bytes;
context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
context.Request.Body.CopyTo(memoryStream);
bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```